# Mapping from useState question - react/Js

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, fetch, mapping

I am having an error mapping a API request from a useState.

My fetch works perfectly and returns an array of objects that I then put into my useState. After that I try to map my useState out so that I only console.log the name field. I am using the code below.

```
const help = mygenres.map((elem) => console.log(elem.name));
```

What I get is an array with zero objects

Then, without refreshing, I use the code below

```
const help = mygenres.genres.map((elem) => console.log(elem.name));
```

And everything works. I get a list of my genres displayed in my console.log

However when I refresh the page, I get a bunch of errors. The only way to fix it is to go back to the first code, save, then again update it to the second code so that it works again until the next time I refresh the page.

Any idea why this is happening and how to fix it? Seems to be working when re-rednering but not when mounting. Does it have something to do with the way my useEffect was setup?

Below is what my fetch returns and what is put into my use state

```
genres: Array(19)
0: {id: 28, name: 'Action'}
1: {id: 12, name: 'Adventure'}
2: {id: 16, name: 'Animation'}
3: {id: 35, name: 'Comedy'}
4: {id: 80, name: 'Crime'}
5: {id: 99, name: 'Documentary'}
6: {id: 18, name: 'Drama'}
7: {id: 10751, name: 'Family'}
8: {id: 14, name: 'Fantasy'}
9: {id: 36, name: 'History'}
10: {id: 27, name: 'Horror'}
11: {id: 10402, name: 'Music'}
12: {id: 9648, name: 'Mystery'}
13: {id: 10749, name: 'Romance'}
14: {id: 878, name: 'Science Fiction'}
15: {id: 10770, name: 'TV Movie'}
16: {id: 53, name: 'Thriller'}
17: {id: 10752, name: 'War'}
18: {id: 37, name: 'Western'}
```

Below is my complete code

```
import React from "react";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function Genrenavbar() {
  const [mygenres, setMygenres] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function APIrequests() {
      const response = await fetch(
        `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/genre/movie/list?api_key=${process.env.REACT_APP_MY_TEST_API}&language=en-US`
      );
      const movie = await response.json();
      console.log(movie);
      setMygenres(movie);
      console.log(mygenres);
    }
    APIrequests();
  }, []);
 
   const help = mygenres.genres.map((elem) => console.log(elem.name));

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: what would happen if you make the initial state to an object with a key of genres? like this: ```const [mygenres, setMygenres] = useState({ genres: [] })```. also you should camelCase myGenres.

Comment: Yes, this seems to work. However, I dont understand why this works and me doing `const [mygenres, setMygenres] = useState()` or even `useState{}` does not work? **Why do I need to list a key in the useState?** When I map a regular array of objects (AKA not fetched) in the useState I do not need to put keys for it to work properly. Why is this?

Comment: @David Grosh sorry forgot to tag you but anyone feel free to jump in also.

Comment: basically any moment the response isn't rendered, that map would be mapping an undefined array

Comment: @David Grosh But shouldn't the response already be returned (as I am using await for the fetch to be returned) and shouldn't it already be set as the state by the time I begin mapping (as I setState inside my useEffect) and starting mapping outside my useEffect?

So I understand your logic of mapping an empty/undefined array and how that can cause a problem...but how can the array be empty or undefined given the above code layout?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit more robust;

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useMemo } from "react";

export default function Genrenavbar() {
  const [mygenres, setMygenres] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(
          `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/genre/movie/list?api_key=${process.env.REACT_APP_MY_TEST_API}&language=en-US`
        );
        const movie = await response.json();
        setMygenres(movie);
      } catch (error) {
        // handle errors here
        console.log({ error });
      }
    })();
  }, []);

  const help = useMemo(() => mygenres?.genres?.map((elem) => elem?.name), [mygenres]);
  console.log(help);
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).